# Xamarin.Forms Different View Per Platform

Tags: xamarin.forms

So I'm new to Xamarin development and I have a question that I haven't been able to find an answer for. Is it possible to implement a view so that it looks different on each platform or maybe even one? IE - The view looks similar on iOS and Android, but for a UWP desktop app it maybe has more available controls because there is more screen space. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at Device class [Device Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I think that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course you can. The simplest way is to use the `OnPlatform` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax#platform-differences-with-onplatform)) tag in your XAML

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
    <On Platform="iOS">
        <!-- Use view for iOS here -->
    </On>
    <On Platform="Android">
        <!-- Use view for Android here -->
    </On>
    <On Platform="UWP">
        <!-- Use view for UWP here -->
    </On>
</OnPlatform>
```

In your case (using the same view for Android and iOS) you could simplify this to

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
    <On Platform="iOS, Android">
        <!-- Use view for iOS here -->
    </On>
    <On Platform="UWP">
        <!-- Use view for UWP here -->
    </On>
</OnPlatform>
```

If you are creating the views in code, you could use `Device.RuntimePlatform`

```
View CreateViewForCurrentPlatform()
{
    switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
    {
        case Device.iOS:
        case Device.Android:
            return new View1();
        case Device.UWP:
            return new View2();
    }
    throw new Exception("Unsupported platform");
}
```

Anyway, since you said that

> [...] for a UWP desktop app it maybe has more available controls because there is more screen space.

you should think about using `Device.Idiom` instead (see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Device.Idiom/)), which allows you to discriminate between tablets, desktops and phones. Android and iOS are running on tablets too and it would be a pity to waste screen space on those.